# Объединение трех таблиц по повторяющимся строкам

Tags: mysql, sql, join

У меня есть таблица `Parent` с перечнем родителей в столбце `ParentId`, таблица `Children` с перечнем детей в столбце `ChilId` и таблица `ParentChildren` с их отношением `(id, ChildId, ParentId)`. У некоторых детей в таблице `Parent` оба родителя, также среди них есть братья-сестры.

Мне нужно получить таблицу, в которой будут перечислены родители-супруги, имеющие двух и более детей. Получается, если в семье два ребенка, то на каждого будет по два родителя, итого два ребенка=4 строки с родителями. Помогите составить Join, пожалуйста

Так у меня получилось выгрузить повторяющиеся id детей, но эта выборка дает только отношение один ребенок-два родителя, а нужно два ребенка-два родителя(по строкам получится как бы 4 родителя):

```
SELECT *
FROM ParentChildren
WHERE ChildId IN (
    SELECT childId FROM ParentChidren
    GROUP BY ChildId HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
ORDER BY ParentId
```

Comment: А что у вас не получается?

Comment: **Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос.** Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, **что именно вызвало у вас трудности** при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: В общем случае нереально. Два ребёнка, мать одна, отцы разные - и какое тут "родители-супруги, имеющие двух и более детей"?

Comment: Так у меня получилось выгрузить повторяюющиеся id детей, но эта выборка дает только отношение один ребенок-два родителя, а нужно два ребенка-два родителя(по строкам получится как бы 4 родителя)
SELECT 
 *
FROM 
 ParentChildren
WHERE 
 ChildId IN (SELECT childId FROM ParentChidren GROUP BY ChildId HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
ORDER BY
 ParentId

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM ParentChildren P1 -- найти все пары ребёнок-родитель
 WHERE EXISTS -- где у родителя ребёнка есть ещё ребёнок 
  (SELECT childId FROM ParentChildren P2
     WHERE P2.childId != P1.childId AND P2.ParentId = P1.ParentId )
AND EXISTS -- и у ребёнка родителя есть второй родитель
  (SELECT ParentId FROM ParentChildren P3
     WHERE P3.childId = P1.childId AND P3.ParentId != P1.ParentId )
```

Comment: спасибо, попробую от этого отталкиваться